# KafkaConsumer reads all the records

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to test a kafka example:
The producer:

```
object ProducerApp extends App {

val topic = "topicTest"
val  props = new Properties()
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "consumer")
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
for(i <- 0 to 20)
{    
val record = new ProducerRecord(topic, "key "+i," value "+i)    
producer.send(record)    
Thread.sleep(100)    
}
}
```

The consumer:

```
object ConsumerApp extends App {
val topic = "topicTest"  
val properties = new Properties
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092")
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "consumer")  
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false")  
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")
properties.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
properties.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](properties)  
consumer.subscribe(scala.List(topic).asJava)    
while (true) {
val records:ConsumerRecords[String,String] = consumer.poll(200)
println("records size "+records.count())    
}  
}
```

The topic "topicTest" is created with 1 partition.

The expected result is:

```
records size 21
records size 21
records size 21
records size 21
...
```

but the obtained result is:

```
records size 21
records size 0
records size 21
records size 0
records size 21
records size 0
...
```

The consumer reads the records alternately. I want to understand the reason.
thank you

Comment: What is the question? Do you need explanation why you see 0 records, or what?

Comment: Yes, I want to know why I see 0 records, Thank you

Comment: I think that at some point, there is no data available yet, so poll returns back after 200ms, but because no data is available to fetch, then it returns empty  list.  This is normal situation, IMHO

Comment: I added "consumer.seekToBeginning(consumer.assignment())", so the consumer must read the data from the beginning every iteration (records size must be 21 every iteration). But I see the (records size 21, records size 0, records size 21, records size 0, ...)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the reason you see this behavior could be the short timeout you set for `poll()`. A timeout of `200` milliseconds may not be enough to retry an internal `pollOnce()` ([link](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/c7ab3efcbe5d34c28e19a5a6a59962c2abfd2235/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.java#L1106)) after an offset reset. The consumer times out after one `pollOnce()` that requires an offset reset and returns no record. On the next loop in your app when `poll()` is called the offset is already what we need to be. So `200` milliseconds is probably enough to retrieve records. On the third call the above behavior repeats.

Note that the call to `seekToBeginning()` does not immediately reset the offset, but flags the partition for an offset reset. The actual reset happens at the next call to`poll()` or `position()`.

Try to increase the `poll()` timeout and that should hopefully get rid of the `record size 0` outputs you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka does not store data in consecutive offsets. Some offsets are left empty. For those offsets you will retrieve an empty array. This is normal, just reject those offsets.